# Elasticsearch | Query over array of objects

Tags: arrays, object, elasticsearch

Lets say I have an object in ES such as:

```
{
  name: "calendar";
  events: [
    {
      birthday: "1992-10-09",
      graduation: "2018-06-15",
      wedding: "2016-12-12"
    }
  ]

}
```

Is there a way I can query over the events array to find an element in the events array that is passed the current date.

So far I have:

```
GET /index/type/_search
{
  "query": {
    "range" : {
      "events" : {
        "gte" : "now"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

but that does not iterate over each object in the array and return the name of the event. For this scenario it should return the object graduation: "2018-06-15". Thanks for the help!

Comment: Can you share the mapping of your index. `GET /index/type/_mapping`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Nested datatypes](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html) to store nested documents inside parent document. 
And to query back the Nested types you can use [Nested Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-nested-query.html).